# How can I convert BinaryType to Array[Byte] when calling Scala UDF in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I've written the following UDF in Scala:

```scala
import java.io.{ByteArrayOutputStream, ByteArrayInputStream}
import java.util.zip.{GZIPInputStream}

def Decompress(compressed: Array[Byte]): String = {
  val inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed))
  val output = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).mkString
  
  return output
}

val decompressUdf = (compressed: Array[Byte]) => {
  Decompress(compressed)
}

spark.udf.register("Decompress", decompressUdf)
```

I'm then attempting to call the UDF with the following:

```scala
val sessionsRawDF =
  sessionRawDF
    .withColumn("WebsiteSession", decompressUdf(sessionRawDF("body")))
    .select(
      current_timestamp().alias("ingesttime"),
      current_timestamp().cast("date").alias("p_ingestdate"),
      col("partition"),
      col("enqueuedTime"),
      col("WebsiteSession").alias("Json")
    )
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> command-130062350733681:9: error: type mismatch;
> found: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
> required: Array[Byte]
> decompressUdf(col("WebsiteSession")).alias("Json")

I was under the impression Spark would implicitly get the value and go from the spark type to Array[Byte] in this case.

Would some please help me understand what's going on, I've been fighting this for a while and not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the Scala function to a Spark UDF first, before you can register it as a UDF. For example,

```
val decompressUdf = udf(Decompress _)

spark.udf.register("Decompress", decompressUdf)
```

In fact, there is no need to register the UDF if you're just using it in the DataFrame API. You can simply run the first line and use `decompressUdf`. Registering is only needed if you want to use the UDF in SQL.